# Fragment Transaction Animation not Working in Android 6.0+

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the `setCustomAnimations()` method to absolutely no effect in Android 6.0.1. All that happens is that the fragment gets stuck for the duration of the animation to the left of the screen leaving a white space on the rest of the screen and then occupies the screen without any animation. It works perfectly in all the versions <6.0. I'm using the method as follows:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations
            (R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, 0, 0);
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment,
            ResourceUtil.resByName(context, R.string.myFragmentText));
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also, the slide_in_left XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_appear, R.anim.s_down);
```

more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html).

Still not working? Check your xml. The -100% may lead to an issue.

So change the animation to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```